# How to get the customer associated to an Alexa device when building a custom alexa skill kit?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When developing a custom alexa skill kit, how to get the customer id or email id registered to the device? Is there a way to implement it.

Comment: Please comment if someone is giving downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the customer id or e-mail address registered to the device.  Amazon has recently added a way to get the postal address (see [their blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/75db99e4-dc77-42d1-89d1-aa8b41301324/build-more-engaging-skills-with-device-address-api-and-gain-insights-with-the-new-metrics-dashboard) about their new [Device Address API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api)) but that is all so far.

If, by chance, you are instead asking about getting a customer id or e-mail by associating your own service's account with the user then you should look into [account linking](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system).